# Android custom lint rule for handling java checked exception in kotlin

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-lint

Since kotlin doesn't have the concept of the checked exception, many times we tend to forget about handling the exception while calling the java function(from kotlin) which `throws` checked exception and it would just crash in case of exception. Since this is the pretty common thing.

Do we have any android custom lint which would just remind us to handle the exception?

Comment: https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-implement-a-custom-lint-rule-in-android-to-warn-against-checked-exception-thrown-from-a076eb9fecd5 might help